# How do I transition a quotation from "Draft" to "Sent" after print?

Tags: python, report, odoo, odoo-8

I have a custom report for Quotations and would like to, on print (generating PDF), transit the quotation from the "Draft" to "Sent" state. How can I achieve this?

Report was written by predecessor in RML. I tried adding a write method to change the state but to no avail:

```
import time
from openerp.report import report_sxw

class customquote(report_sxw.rml_parse):
        def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context):
            super(customquote, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
            self.localcontext.update({
                'time': time,
            })
            sale_order = self.pool.get('sale.order')
            order_id = sale_order.search(cr,uid,[('name','=',name)])
            order = sale_order.browse(cr,uid,order_id)
            for record in order:
                print record
                record.write({'state': 'sent'})
                #Neither of the following worked at either...
                #record.state = 'sent'
                #record.signal_workflow('quotation_sent')

report_sxw.report_sxw(
    'report.sale.order.customquote',
    'sale.order',
    'My_Quotation/report/customquote.rml',
    parser=customquote,
    header=False,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround by using additional buttons on the form page instead. Note 'sale.order.my_quotation' is the custom report that was previously created.

1. my_sale.py

   from openerp.osv import osv, fields

   class my_sale_order(osv.osv):

   ```
   _inherit = 'sale.order'

   def print_quotation_custom(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
       #Copied from /sale/sale.py
       assert len(ids) == 1,
       self.signal_workflow(cr, uid, ids, 'quotation_sent')
       return self.pool['report'].get_action(cr, uid, ids, 'sale.order.my_quotation', context=context)
   ```
2. my_sale_view.xml

   ```
   <record id="view_order_form_custom" model="ir.ui.view">
     <field name="model">sale.order</field>
     <field name="name">sale.order.form.inherit</field>
     <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
     <field name="arch" type="xml">
       <xpath expr="//form/header/button[@name='print_quotation']" position="replace">
             <button name="print_quotation_custom" string="Print" type="object" states="draft" class="oe_highlight" groups="base.group_user"/>
       </xpath>
       <xpath expr="//form/header/button[@name='print_quotation']" position="after">
             <button name="print_quotation_custom" string="Print" type="object" states="sent,progress,manual" groups="base.group_user"/>
       </xpath>
     </field>
   </record>
   ```
3. **init**.py

   import ioi_quotation #added this
4. **openerp**.py

   {
   'name': 'My Sale',
   'version': '1.0',
   'category':'Sales',
   'description': 'My custom sale module',
   'author': 'jeszy',
   'depends':['base','sale'],
   'data': ['my_sale_view.xml'],
   'demo': [],
   'installable': True,
   'auto_install': False,
   }